# What SCM-based blog engines are there?

Tags: svn, git, mercurial, blog-engine

Recently I came across a blog engine that works in quite unusual way. It polls a git repository and publishes a blog post after something new has been found in the repo. The post is generated as a static HTML and put somewhere in public_html. Homepage gets updated.

Do you know any git/hg/svn based blog engines like this? Let's create a list of all SCM-based blog engines as a **community wiki**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use [GitHub for your own blog](https://github.com/blog/164-use-github-as-your-blog).
See the details in this post "[Publishing a Blog with GitHub Pages and Jekyll](http://blog.envylabs.com/2009/08/publishing-a-blog-with-github-pages-and-jekyll/)".

[Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) can be used with any SCM - this is just a static site generator suitable for blogs. To start up quickly, get [jekyll-template](https://github.com/christianhellsten/jekyll-template).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it. However, I'm interested only in a repo and blog engine that I host myself

Comment: Jekyll turned out to be most interesting. This is just a static site generator suitable for blogs. What I like most in Jekyll is the fact that it can be used with any SCM and is the fastest to set up. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info/) is a similar idea for wikis.  It contains a few plugins that make it readily useable as a blog.

Comment: Some real running examples are listed at http://ikiwiki.info/ikiwikiusers/ (see the "Personal sites and blogs" section).

Answer (score 5):

I've been using the Mercurial based blohg and have found it to be excellent:

- Blohg home: http://hg.rafaelmartins.eng.br/blohg/
- My blohg: http://ry4an.org/unblog/
- My backing repo: http://ry4an.org/hg/unblog/

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found for git:

- Shinmun: http://github.com/georgi/shinmun
- git-blog: http://github.com/elliottcable/git-blog
- Wheat: http://github.com/creationix/wheat

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of git-based Wiki & Blog engines:
https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools#Wikis.2C_blogs.2C_etc.